# LOGNORM.INV function of excel in python scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to implement the below excel function in python and need to create 10k such calculations. How can I implement this logic in scipy  ? Can I use [lognormal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) api of scipy to get lognormal inverse ?

`B10 - Probability event will happen
C10 - Lower bound
D10 - Upper bound`

`=IF(RAND()<B10,LOGNORM.INV(RAND(),(LN(D10)+LN(C10))/2, (LN(D10)-LN(C10))/3.29),0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameterization of SciPy's [`lognorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) implementation of the log-normal disribution is not the same as that of Excel's [LOGNORM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOGNORM-INV-function-FE79751A-F1F2-4AF8-A0A1-E151B2D4F600) functions.  Excel uses the mean and standard deviation of the underlying normal distribution.  To convert those to the SciPy shape `s`, location `loc` and scale `scale`, use:

```
s = standard_dev
loc = 0
scale = np.exp(mean)
```

`LOGNORM.INV(p, mean, standard_dev)` computes the inverse of the CDF.  The corresponding method of SciPy's `lognorm` object is `ppf` (the [percent-point function](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda362.htm); scroll down in the reference page to find the discussion of the percent point function).

So to compute the equivalent of `LOGNORM.INV(p, mean, standard_dev)`, you can use

```
lognorm.ppf(p, standard_dev, loc=0, scale=np.exp(mean))
```

See [Calculate Scipy LOGNORM.CDF() and get the same answer as MS Excel LOGNORM.DIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208141/calculate-scipy-lognorm-cdf-and-get-the-same-answer-as-ms-excel-lognorm-dist) for a similar question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works great.